# Looking to find values in one dataframe and input them into another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

So, I have 5 dataframes that I need to loop through and they all follow a similar format:

RX Dataframe

[image]

And here is the final dataframe:

[image]

So, essentially I need to pull the cluster of a specific index in the first martrx and find :

- If that index is present in the new dataframe
- If it is, find it and put the cluster value in the appropriate column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out:

```
for i in final_inds:
    for j in range(0,5):
        try:
            cluster_values = all_dfs[j].loc[i,"clusters"]
        except:
            cluster_values = -1

        final_df.loc[i, cols[j]] = cluster_values

final_df.head()
```